# Clojure tail recursion with lazy-seq

Tags: clojure

Could you kindly explain in more breadth and clarity, how does `lazy-seq` make tail recursion "safe" as per this docs page?

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq

```
;; The following defines a lazy-seq of all positive numbers.  Note that 
;; the lazy-seq allows us to make a recursive call in a safe way because
;; the call does not happen immediately but instead creates a closure.

user=> (defn positive-numbers 
    ([] (positive-numbers 1))
    ([n] (lazy-seq (cons n (positive-numbers (inc n))))))
#'user/positive-numbers

user=> (take 5 (positive-numbers))
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: When you make a function call (in most languages), you push a new frame on to the call stack. If you did that repeatedly generating an infinite sequence of numbers (either recursively or by looping) you'd eventually you'd overflow. By using lazy evaluation, you only recurse as many times as the argument to `take`.

Comment: @JaredSmith In fact you add only a small, constant number of frames to the stack, regardless of the argument to `take`. It's easy to see for yourself that your explanation can't work: try writing `(last (take 1e6 (range)))`, and observe that even though your JVM does not have space for a million stack frames you still get the right answer.

Comment: @amalloy I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of `lazy-seq` you will see it indeed returns a closure (a function which holds on to a piece of context):

```
(list 'new 'clojure.lang.LazySeq (list* '^{:once true} fn* [] body))
```

So the call to `positive-numbers` in `(cons n (positive-numbers (inc n))` is not evaluated immediately, but delayed until the closure gets called.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of `lazy-seq` you'll notice that it's a macro that packages its argument in a function body:

```
user=> (source lazy-seq)
(defmacro lazy-seq
  "Takes a body of expressions that returns an ISeq or nil, and yields
  a Seqable object that will invoke the body only the first time seq
  is called, and will cache the result and return it on all subsequent
  seq calls. See also - realized?"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& body]
  (list 'new 'clojure.lang.LazySeq (list* '^{:once true} fn* [] body)))
```

Which produces something like this:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(lazy-seq (cons 1 (lazy-seq [2 3 4]))))
(new clojure.lang.LazySeq (fn* [] (cons 1 (lazy-seq [2 3 4]))))
```

This gives you a hint what is happening: execution of the tail position is deferred until it's' required. How is this achieved? Look at [clojure/lang/LazySeq.java (Copyright (c) Rich Hickey. All rights reserved)](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L37):

```
final synchronized Object sval(){
  if(fn != null)
    {
                sv = fn.invoke();
                fn = null;
    }
  if(sv != null)
    return sv;
  return s;
}

final synchronized public ISeq seq(){
  sval();
  if(sv != null)
    {
    Object ls = sv;
    sv = null;
    while(ls instanceof LazySeq)
      {
      ls = ((LazySeq)ls).sval();
      }
    s = RT.seq(ls);
    }
  return s;
}
```

These two methods execute the callable to get the tail values out -- they also unwind contained LazySeq if they see one. Then cache the result.